# Convert SQL subquery to Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, subquery, dax, measure

As a newbie of PowerBI, I was so struggled with this problem. I want to create a custom measure, and it can be solved easily with SQL statement which looks like this:

```
select count(*) from Task
 where case_num in(
    select case_num from Task
     where task_type="DDD") sub
```

Can somebody help me with this. Thank you!!!!!

[The table is roughly like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqA6Z.png)

Comment: Add sample data with your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can isolate the case_nums that have a specific task type

```
VAR tbl = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[case_num]),'Table'[task_type] = "DDD")
```

And then apply that table as a filter:

```
Measure = 
VAR tbl = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[case_num]),'Table'[task_type] = "DDD")
RETURN CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[case_num]), TREATAS(tbl,'Table'[case_num]))
```

or

```
Measure = 
VAR tbl = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[case_num]),'Table'[task_type] = "DDD")
RETURN CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[case_num]), 'Table'[case_num] IN tbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure

```
_count =
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Task[CaseNum] ), FILTER ( Task, Task[task_type] = "DDD" ) )
```

**`Edit`**

If you have a small number of tasks which you want to use in filter, you can use this

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Task[Case] ), FILTER ( Task, Task[task_type] IN {"BB","AA","DDD","CC"}))
```

If you have a large number of tasks that you don't want to manually type in filter, then create a lookup table first and use that in a measure

```
TaskLookUpTable = DATATABLE ( --a long list of task; hence taskTbl
    "task_type", STRING,   
    {
        { "BB"},
        { "AA"},
        { "DDD"},
        { "CC"}
    }
)

Measure2 = --create the above table first before writing this measure
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Task[Case] ),
    TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'TaskLookUp'[task_type] ), Task[task_type] )
)
```

Comment: Thx!!! But I'm afraid it might not be the case. Could u please check the image I just added. A case can have different task types. There is only one "DDD"-type record, but I want to find out all the rows with these specific case_num(s).