# Need support on DAX SUBquery for multiple tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

0

I have 3 tables which I have mentioned in the below SQL Query, which I need to convert into a DAX formula which I'm not able to do as a newbie to Power BI, which similarly I need to do the same for almost 5 - 6 columns.

If this has figured out, I can do the remaining 5 DAX Calculated columns, which I need support on writing Complex DAX for below SQL

```
    SELECT 
 Substr(TableA.Text_Noted,0,500)
 FROM   SYS_DATA_NODE_TAB TableA, SYS_DATA_NOTED TableC
 WHERE  TableA.ID_Name = TableC.ID_Name
 AND    TableA.task_note_text LIKE '%Field update Sender:%'
 AND    TableA.task_note_entered_date =
        (
               SELECT Max(TableB.task_note_entered_date)
               FROM   SYS_DATA_NODE_TAB TableB, SYS_DATA_NOTED TableC
               WHERE  TableB.task_note_text LIKE '%Field update Sender:%'
               AND    TableB.ID_Name = TableC.ID_Name )
 AND    rownum = 1  as Text_Noted;
```

Please support on this or help me guidance in writing this Complex DAX.

Thanks

Comment: This questions doesn't make sense. All the data manipulations you have to do in the advanced editor by suing M queries. Dax is for calculations not for data manipulation

Comment: Hi @AmilaMGunawardana 

Thanks for the update.

Actually, this is a calculated column logic which is SQL query generated by OBIEE tool. This kind of calculations can be done in DAX and whatever the source I'm using is a liveconnection which i dont have option to do MQuery.

For your reference , I'm share a different link which a subquery can be created into DAX formula please refer below 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273577/convert-sql-subquery-to-power-bi-dax

But my requirement is bit complex

Thanks,

Comment: Yes this is a measure DAX is used to do measures like that you needs to have calculated column.What you need a calculated column right? Are these tables already joined? How was the modeling part? Can i have a ss of the modeling?

Comment: Ya we have joins of it, model is properly built. As per sensitive i cant share the screenshot.